# Why does openapi-generator use imports that do not exist

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using `openapi-codegen version 4.2.2` and `openapi specification 3.0.0` to generate a java server API from a yaml file like this:

`openapi-generator generate -i test.yaml -g spring -o /tmp/springTest`

The problem I encounter is, that the generated code tries to import a class that does not exist. The API should accept an object of type pet and return the same pet. A Pet should be a Cat, Dog, or Lizard. I used the inheritence example from the openapi specification and build the following yaml file from it:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Three Pets
  termsOfService: http://swagger.io/terms
tags:
  - name: test
paths:
  /echoPet:
    post:
      tags:
        - test
      summary: Return input
      description: Send pet get pet
      operationId: echoPet
      parameters:
        - name: pet
          in: query
          schema:
            oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Lizard'
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Pet sucesfully returned
          content:
            application/json:
                schema:
                  oneOf:
                    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
servers:
  - url: https://localhost:8080/v2
  - url: http://localhost:8080/v2
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      required:
      - pet_type
      properties:
        pet_type:
          type: string
      discriminator:
        propertyName: pet_type
        mapping:
          cachorro: Dog
    Cat:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      - type: object
        # all other properties specific to a `Cat`
        properties:
          name:
            type: string
          huntingSkill:
            type: string
            description: The measured skill for hunting
            enum:
            - clueless
            - lazy
            - adventurous
            - aggressive
    Dog:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      - type: object
        # all other properties specific to a `Dog`
        properties:
          bark:
            type: string
          packSize:
            type: integer
            format: int32
            description: the size of the pack the dog is from
            default: 0
            minimum: 0
    Lizard:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      - type: object
        # all other properties specific to a `Lizard`
        properties:
          lovesRocks:
            type: boolean
```

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#discriminator-object

As far as I understand it, it should generate an API that acceps oneOf the following types Cat,Dog,Lizard. (If I use Pet here, the validation says, Pet is not of type object)
The generated EchoPetApi.java uses imports for:

```
import org.openapitools.model.OneOfCatDogLizard;
import org.openapitools.model.OneOfPet;
```

But these classes do not exist, which will make the code not compilable. All I have in the org.openapitools.model package is:

```
Cat.java
CatAllOf.java
Dog.java
DogAllOf.java
Lizard.java
LizardAllOf.java
Pet.java
```

Here the Cat, Dog and Lizard.java look as expected and all extend Pet.java, but CatAllOf, DogAllOf and LizardAllOf do not extend anything but only have properties from the respective class and a slightly different hashCode() method.

Here is the EchoPetApi.java with the not existing imports(first two, after the package):

```
/**
 * NOTE: This class is auto generated by OpenAPI Generator (https://openapi-generator.tech) (4.2.2).
 * https://openapi-generator.tech
 * Do not edit the class manually.
 */
package org.openapitools.api;

import org.openapitools.model.OneOfCatDogLizard;
import org.openapitools.model.OneOfPet;
import io.swagger.annotations.*;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2019-12-18T11:27:04.474+01:00[Europe/Berlin]")

@Validated
@Api(value = "echoPet", description = "the echoPet API")
public interface EchoPetApi {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Return input", nickname = "echoPet", notes = "Send pet get pet", response = OneOfPet.class, tags={ "test", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Pet sucesfully returned", response = OneOfPet.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/echoPet",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    default ResponseEntity<OneOfPet> echoPet(@ApiParam(value = "", defaultValue = "null") @Valid OneOfCatDogLizard pet) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }

}
```

If I use the validate function from openapi-codegen it does not return any errors:

```
$ openapi-generator validate -i test.yaml
Validating spec (test.yaml)
No validation issues detected.
```

Comment: Updated the openapi-generator to the new version 4.3.0, but it does not fix the issure.

Comment: @schade: Was your issue resolved ? Facing something similar with `anyOf`

Comment: No, nothing new.

Comment: Found a way to fix this?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have not been able to find out anything new yet.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue does anyone know is it already supported in openapi-generator?

Comment: Faced this issue again for the second time. Still no resolution. AFAIK the only solution is to rework the Open API spec to use inheritance instead of OneOf

Answer (score 0):

I've done some changes on your openapi specification to make it work on my side

The first thing to change is on the parameters/input for your API. It is complicated to send your object as a query String

```yaml
     parameters:
        - name: pet
          in: query
          schema:
            oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Lizard'
```

So prefer a requestBody and define it like this :

```yaml
    requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Lizard'
```

Then, the response can be managed like this (oneOf instruction is not mandatory for your case) :

```yaml
    responses:
        "200":
          description: Pet sucesfully returned
          content:
            application/json:
                schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
```

The generator will now deliver an interface used by `Cat`, `Dog` and `Lizard`

[image: generated model]

The controller will use this interface and you will have no more compilation/definitions issues

Answer (score 0):

## Why is the extra class generated?

The reason the `*AllOf` classes are generated is because the openapi generator looks at the nested schema within the class definitions as a separate schema. Looking at the Lizard example:

```yaml
Lizard:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
    - type: object
    # all other properties specific to a `Lizard`
    properties:
      lovesRocks:
        type: boolean
```

Here, we have three schemas defined.

1. Lizard
2. Pet
3. Anonymous schema with no name that defines the other half of Lizard

For example, consider if you added an additional property to your lizard, but included this property outside of the `allOf` schema:

```yaml
Lizard:
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
    - type: object
      # all other properties specific to a `Lizard`
      properties:
        lovesRocks:
          type: boolean
```

This new object definition will still pass the validation, and still contains three separate schemas.  However, now the Lizard.java will contain a new field `private String name;` that does not exist in `LizardAllOf.java`.  The other thing to consider is that the `LizardAllOf` class does not extend `Pet`, whereas, the `Lizard.java` class does.

## Prevent the additional class generation

So, how do we fix this?  If you are content with never using the `AllOf` classes, then the solution is fairly simple.  You can use the `.openapi-generator-ignore` file to ignore generation of any classes that end in `AllOf`.

Just add the line `**/*AllOf.java` to the `.openapi-generator-ignore` and those files will no longer be generated.

Remember though, that `allOf` isn't the only polymorphic keyword in openapi that will generate additional classes; `oneOf` will also do this.  I would recommend naming your internal schemas using `title`.  This will allow you to take control of the names and ignore everything the same way.  For example:

```yaml
Lizard:
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
    - title: LizardDetails
      type: object
      # all other properties specific to a `Lizard`
      properties:
        lovesRocks:
          type: boolean
```

Now, instead of `AllOf`, you will get a new object called `LizardDetails`.  This helps in identifying objects that you have explicitly defined, and objects you have forgotten to define, which can really help in large, complex schemas.  Now, when you add `**/*Details.java` to your `.openapi-generator-ignore`, you will be able to exclude only classes whose titles you have explicitly defined, and will not inadvertently exclude classes you aren't aware of.

## Remove unused imports

In the current version of `openapi-generator` (6.2.0 as of writing), this appears to be enough.  However, in previous versions of the generator, the imports for the ignored files were still generated.  This would cause compilation errors similar to what you described.

To fix compilation errors based on imports that don't exist, you can use [spotless from diffplug](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless).  Simply set the spotless plugin to [`removeUnusedImports`](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/blob/main/lib/src/main/java/com/diffplug/spotless/java/RemoveUnusedImportsStep.java).  Since you are using the CLI generator, you can setup spotless via [file post processing](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/file-post-processing.md).

For others coming here that are using the gradle or maven plugins, you can setup spotless via the [gradle plugin](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-gradle) or the [maven plugin](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-maven).

Any other linting tool will likely work as well, so long as it is able to remove unused imports, I just prefer spotless.